# Cloudfront SSL images not loading in IE8

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have some cloudfront distributions set up, that work fine serving images over ssl in chrome, firefox, and IE9, but in IE8 they fail, but not for everyone. Maybe half or more fail that have tried it. This is my test url:

https://d36kjak8b8jsqp.cloudfront.net/12055125/images/desert.jpg

Comment: BTW here's an example, not even in my ditribution that doesn't work in IE8: https://dzxjrjfdtjbo0.cloudfront.net/cloudfront-jobs.html

Comment: You can't run Fiddler locally for SSL, since the Fiddler proxy would have to do the SSL handshake. Unless you have this set up, which most people don't, it won't work. Consider using Firebug for Firefox instead.

Comment: Yeah the fiddler thing isn't the main problem. Even without fiddler IE8 won't load the images.

Comment: hmmm, anyone able to reproduce this ? (just click the url in the first comment, in IE 8). Starting a conversation on AWS forums. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=234249

Comment: I see the AWS team was able to help you solve your problem. Do you have an acceptable solution for anyone else that might hit this page or is it private?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS ops team was able to solve my problem. It turned out to be a deployment script we run internally that disables certain security ciphers used by Cloudfront. These are controlled by registry keys for IE8, which I guess is why it only affects IE8 and not other browsers. If you have this problem just check the AWS forum post here and send a private message to the AWS team. They seemed very helpful and right on target after I sent some http logs in.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=234249